# How to download big table like MySQL into my pc?

Tags: download, bigtable

How to download big table like MySQL into my pc?

Comment: this question needs to be clarified.  Are you talking about downloading the contents of the app engine datastore?  are you talking about downloading all the data google has ever stored in bigtable?  Are you asking if google allows you to download an executable version of bigtable that you could set up on your own servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppScale is a platform that allows users to deploy and host their own Google App Engine applications. It executes automatically over Amazon EC2 and Eucalyptus as well as Xen and KVM. It has been developed and is maintained by the RACELab at UC Santa Barbara. It supports both the Python and Java Google App Engine platforms.

http://code.google.com/p/appscale/

Comment: @zjm1126 If you want the software, you need Hadoop or Hypertable, not AppScale.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can [download](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) the contents of your datastore in a number of formats.

Comment: i want to download the database "bigtable" <-- the database of google , not only  the contents .

Comment: @zjm1126 bigtable is proprietary.  Google doesn't distribute it.

Comment: @zjm1126 What do you mean you want to download "bigtable"? @dfichter's link describes how to download your App Engine data in multiple formats, what else do you want to download, specifically?

Comment: @zjm1126 - I don't think you have enough hard drives to download everything google has stored in bigtable.

Comment: I think what he's talking about is downloading the DBMS software and not the data.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Bigtable DBMS is proprietary, so you can't download it to your PC.

Two non-proprietary alternatives you might consider are HBase and Cassandra. Both are based on the Bigtable model.